# Shuffling Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I have two arrays with a series of integers. I want to simulate cutting a deck of cards repeatedly to 'shuffle the deck'.  I set a cut position and assign everything before the cut in Array A to the start of Array B.  I realize I need to use slice to avoid just creating a reference to Array A, but can I use slice on both sides of the equation, i.e. `arrayB.slice(0,3) = arrayA.slice(49,52)` ?

Comment: I see slice returns a new array.  I'm trying to do this with only two arrays, so I'm wondering how I can copy a slice of an array into my new array at an arbitrary index position.  It seems to be just copying reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if repeated cuttings really mimics a shuffle, but maybe it's not all you're doing. Anyway, based on what I understand of your description, you want:

```
arrayB = arrayA.splice(49,52).concat( arrayB );
```

This should result in a modified `arrayB` having the pieces which were removed from `arrayA` in front of what it had previously held.

If you *do not* want `arrayA` modified such that what goes to `arrayB` is no longer in `arrayA`, then you use `Array.prototype.slice()` instead of `Array.prototype.splice()`.

Using `splice()`:

```
var a = [ 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4' ];
var b = [ 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4' ];
b = a.splice( 0, 2 ).concat( b );
// a is now: [ 'a3', 'a4' ]
// b is now: [ 'a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4' ]
```

Operating on both arrays to cause each to receive from the other:

```
var a = [ 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4' ];
var b = [ 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4' ];

var removedFromA = a.splice( 0, 2 );
var removedFromB = b.splice( 0, 2 );

b = removedFromA.concat( b );
a = removedFromB.concat( a );

// a is now: [ 'b1', 'b2', 'a3', 'a4' ]
// b is now: [ 'a1', 'a2', 'b3', 'b4' ]
```

Comment: In sample 1 ("Using splice()..."), what is that syntax called?  I thought I had to call splice as follows:
deckA.splice(startIndex,numberToReplace,Element1...ElementN);
NEVERMIND, I got it, I'm calling concat on the array returned by splice() method.  Excellent!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I finally resorted to this code:
deckB=deckA.splice(0,cutPos);
deckB=deckA.concat(deckB);
That's one cut with the result to the second deck.  Then copy B to A for next operation with:
deckA=deckB.slice(0,16);

Comment: No problem, glad you have something working the way you like. :)

Comment: Then I ended up with:
deckB=deckA.splice(cutPos,deckA.length-cutPos).concat(deckA); // which is exactly your solution in the first box, thanks again!  I was worried that the deckA version being concatenated to the splice would be the 'pre-splice' deckA, but it apparently is not!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense to assign anything to a return value of a function like you do in your example.

Try to look into the **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method, it should give you what you need.

Example:

```
var a = arrayA.splice(0,10); //remove the first 10 elements from arrayA and assign them to a
var b = arrayB.splice(0,10); //see above;
Array.prototype.push.apply(arrayA,b); //add the elements you removed from ArrayB to arrayA
Array.prototype.push.apply(arrayB,a); //see above.
```

Comment: Splice is exactly what I needed, much obliged.

Comment: That works, for sure, and you're exactly correct about the assignment issue. But I was under the impression that @Stephen wanted what was removed from one array to go to the front of the other.  `Array.prototype.push()` puts them on the end.

Comment: Wait, no, that doesn't work. `Array.prototype.push()` sets the Array which resulted from the splice as the last element of the Array onto which it was pushed. So you end up with something like `[ 1, 2, Array[] ]` When I first saw it I thought `.push()` must be doing something magic I didn't know about and was slightly embarrassed for having suggested `.concat()`. Upon testing, however, I see that `.concat()` was correct.

Comment: @JAAulde: You are correct, concat or Array.prototype.push.apply would be the way to go, now fixed. The reason why i push to the end instead of unshifting is since the OP want's to cut the deck from the top, so adding to the top will mean cutting the same cards the next time.

Comment: Wanted to restrict assignments to the two arrays though.  See my comments to JAAulde below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really 100% clear from your question if you are looking for a good way to shuffle  deck of cards, or if you want more information about `slice`.  For this answer I'll assume the former.

It's actually very easy to get a seemingly-simple thing like shuffling [wrong](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).  (Wrong in the sense that your shuffling approach can easily have a bias and make some combinations much more common than others).

A better way to shuffle is to use an algorithm like the [Fisher-Yates Shuffling Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

I did this for a card game I wrote (in Javascript) and here's the code I used:

```
// this.drawPile is an array of cards
var n = this.drawPile.length;
while (n > 1) {
    n--;
    var k = Math.floor((n + 1) * Math.random());
    var temp = this.drawPile[k];
    this.drawPile[k] = this.drawPile[n];
    this.drawPile[n] = temp;
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't cutting the deck 100 times still work in theory since, hypothetically, a clumsy shuffler might do just that?

Comment: Apologies, I misapplied the definition of 'cutting the deck'.  One cut maintains sequence.  I was referring to 'slide shuffle' with repeated cuts not 'riffle' or 'dovetail' shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't completely relevant if you want to simulate complete randomness when shuffling two sides of the decks, try this...

```
const shuffle = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if(!(arr1 instanceof Array) || !(arr2 instanceof Array)) return [];
  let ar1 = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? [...arr1] : [...arr2];
  let ar2 = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? [...arr2] : [...arr1];
  let x = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
    if(x > ar2.length-1) break;
    ar1.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (ar1.length+1)), 0, ar2[x]);
    x+=1;
  }
  return ar1;
};
```